# How can I return from a C# 8 switch expression into a property and two locally declared variables?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I have this code which works good:

```
        var (msg, isCC, upd) = Settings.Mode switch
        {
            MO.Learn => ("Use this mode when you are first learning the phrases and their meanings.",
                                Settings.Cc == CC.H,
                                false),
            MO.Practice => ("Use this mode to help you memorize the phrases and their meanings.",
                                Settings.Cc == CC.H,
                                false),
            MO.Quiz => ("Use this mode to run a self marked test.",
                                Settings.Cc == CC.H,
                                true),
            _ => ("", false, false)
        };
```

But in the actual app I want to return a value into a property that's assigned to in multiple places here:

```
    string _modeMessage2;
    public string ModeMessage2 { get => _modeMessage2; set => SetProperty(ref _modeMessage2, value); }
```

Trying this doesn't work:

```
        var (this.ModeMessage2, isCC, upd) = Settings.Mode switch
        {
            MO.Learn => ("Use this mode when you are first learning the phrases and their meanings.",
                                Settings.Cc == CC.H,
                                false),
            MO.Practice => ("Use this mode to help you memorize the phrases and their meanings.",
                                Settings.Cc == CC.H,
                                false),
            MO.Quiz => ("Use this mode to run a self marked test.",
                                Settings.Cc == CC.H,
                                true),
            _ => ("", false, false)
        };
```

Does anyone know how I can return the value into ModeMesage2 without adding in some code like below?

```
ModeMessage2 = msg;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity. Is this code targeting .net framework or core or something else? Just wondering the programming constructs

Comment: It's Microsoft C# 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all items on the left are fields or properties then it will work, if you then try to change one of the items to an expression like `var isCC` then you'll get a compiler error saying you cannot mix expressions and declarations.

So unfortunately this is not supported.